# Why do I get: "error: assignment to expression with array type"

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization, variable-assignment

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[10];
    arr = "Hello";
    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code shows compiler error:

```
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:5:9: error: assignment to expression with array type
     arr = "Hello";
         ^
t.c:6:12: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s",arr);
            ^
```

Whereas the below code works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char arr[10] = "Hello";
    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Both look identical to me. What am I missing here?

Comment: int arr[10] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

Comment: char *arr = "Hello";

Comment: char arr[] = "Hello";

Comment: arr[0] = 'H'; arr[1] = 'e'; arr[2] = 'l'; arr[3] = 'l'; arr[4] = 'o';

Comment: Both are errors. If your compiler does not give error for the second case then you need to reconfigure it.

Comment: Note, if you do load an int array with a char per cell, `printf()` with `%s` format will print either nothing or one character depending on the 'edianness' because it stops upon encountering the first NULL, or `\0` or 0, etc... And each int will be 0x000000xx, where xx is the ASCII value of your character. So printf if going left to right would see '00' immediately and print nothing or the other way would see xx 00 00 00 and just print xx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are **not** identical.

First of all, it makes zero sense to initialize an `int` array with a string literal, and in worst case, it may invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as pointer to integer conversion and the validity of the converted result thereafter is highly platform-specific behaviour. In this regard, both the snippets are invalid.

Then, correcting the data type, considering the `char` array is used,

- In the first case,

  ```
    arr = "Hello";
  ```

is an **[assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science))**, which is not allowed with an array type as LHS of assignment.

- OTOH,

  ```
    char arr[10] = "Hello";
  ```

is an **[initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming))** statement, which is perfectly valid statement.

Comment: My compiler gives the error (for the initialization form): z.c:2:8: error: initializing wide char array with non-wide string literal
   int x[10] = "foo";

Comment: The initialization is not "perfectly valid" because a char array cannot be the initializer for an int, this is a constraint violation

Comment: Ok, imperfectly valid, then. It's the thought that counts. It would be valid if it were a char array though!

Comment: it's not valid semantics because of the type mismatch.  You seem to be suggesting the second one is less bad in some way than the first one but it isn't, they are both clear errors

Comment: @M.M I agree both are wrong, my target was to point out that, if the data type is fixed, the second one would work but the first one would not. How to reflect that in my answer, any suggestions?

Answer (score -3):

Don't know how your second code is working (its not working in my case PLEASE TELL ME WHAT CAN BE THE REASON) it is saying: `array of inappropriate type (int) initialized with string constant`

Since you can't just assign a whole `string` to a `integer` variable.
but you can assign a single `character` to a `int` variable like:
`int a[5]={'a','b','c','d','d'}`